# Only change value in cell if corresponding OptionButton is selected

Tags: excel, vba

**1) Excel Table**

```
             A            B           C     
1    OptionButton1        0
2    OptionButton2        0
3    OptionButton3        0
4
5
```

**2) UserForm1**

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 0
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = 0
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```

I have a `UserForm1` consisting of three `OptionButtons`. 
Once the User clicks on an `OptionButton` the corresponding value in `Column B` is changed from `0` to `1`. 
All this works the way it should.

---

Now, I have the issue that for example if the User clicks on `OptionButton1` the value in `Cell B1` changes from `0` to `1`. 
Then the User decides to switch from `OptionButton1` to `OptionButton2`. 
In this moment the value in `Cell B2` changes from `0` to `1`.
However, in this moment the value in `Cell B1` remains `1` and is not switched back to `0`.

How do I have to modify my code so only the value which is selected in the `OptionButtons` is changed from `0` to `1` in `Column B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the other cells back to 0 if one of the `OptionButton` are selected.

For example with `OptionButton1`

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 1
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = 0
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = 0
Else
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```

As you can't 'unselect' an option button by clicking it the `Else` clause is a bit redundant being in a `OptionButton1_Click` event too.

If you catch the `Change` event instead, you could leave your code as is which means it will then fire whenever the state of the `OptionButton` changes (either `Value = True` or `Value = False`.

The below code would produce the same outcome as if you adopt the above solution.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 1
Else
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = 0
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = 1
Else
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = 0
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Change()
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = 1
Else
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```